# How to interact with DOM without Javascript?

Tags: google-chrome, awesomium, chromium-embedded

How can I interact with `DOM` in either `CEF` or `Awesomium` without using `Javascript`? Why do we have to use `Javascript` just to interact with `DOM`?

Comment: W.r.t CEF: Do you want access to the DOM-tree as a tree, or do you just want to get access to all DOM-elements?

Comment: @Sharadh Full access just like ActiveX IE. With its `IHtmlElement`.. :)

Comment: Did you try out Webkit? Any luck?

Answer (score 3):

**CEF**

While CEF allows access to the DOM via it's `CefDOMVisitor, CefDOMDocument, CefDOMNode, CefDOMEvent and CefDOMEventListener` declared in `cef_dom.h`, chief contributor Marshall Greenblatt confirms [here](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=634) that it is meant for read only access:

> The DOM API exposed by Chromium is read-only with the exception of
>   adding listeners. CEF exposes this same API via the CefFrame::VisitDOM
>   method. If you want to manipulate the DOM directly via C++ it will be
>   necessary to use WebKit interfaces directly.

So, if you'd like full access similar to `IHtmlElement`, you might have to use Webkit directly...

Comment: For first. It is depends from a task. It is exist remote debugging protocol, - there is basis on which work web inspector. It is allow very many things. Second - just use JS for DOM access. What's a problem to do it?